# Whirlpool tub never cleaned for a decade

Tags: bathtub, cleaning

I purchased a condo with an Aker whirlpool tub and it was badly neglected. There is so much mold and mildew buildup. I ran through several cycles with hot water and vinegar and I'm sure the pipes are cleaned out, but it's the jets themselves that are disgusting. I took off the trim rings and cleaned with bleach and a brush, but to really deep clean, I need to take out the assembly and scrub it all down. Here's an example of the foot jets.

[image]

I don't know how to clean it any further. I splash water into it and more mildew comes out. How can I either remove the assembly or clean it while it's still in? I'm thinking of a water pick, but I don't want to spend the money just to clean these out.

Comment: See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/266262/18078 (TL:DR there are better chemicals specifically made for this common problem)

Comment: Note that on some spas, you can remove the inner piece.  They just pop out and in.  Go to a store, spot a spa with similar jets and ask the sales guy how to remove them for cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

connect a garden hose to a washing machine or dishwasher spigot and spray some water in there.

Get some sodium hypochlorite from a swimming pool place and run that through it (it's basically bleach at bulk pricing), it should be more effective than vinegar.

Comment: Check with the manufacturers first, if you can identify them. They may recommend bromine rather than chlorine, or some ot variant of pool disinfectant chemistry/bleach, as kinder to the specific materials they used in constructing the spa.